# Save text from Vue Quill Editor as markdown format

Tags: vue.js, rich-text-editor, quill

is there any way to store texts of Vue Quill Editor, which uses Quill Editor as MD format?

I am trying to build a Text Editor which will also have a Native Android app and I need some common ground to store and display our texts
any replacement or suggestions are welcomed